# Javascript Apps Script search string in object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Help, i have the following function:

```
    function checkSubstring(arraynya,findnya) {
  if (arraynya.includes(findnya)) {
    Logger.log("The substring "+findnya+" exists within the main string.");
  } else {
    Logger.log("The substring "+findnya+" does not exist within the main string.");
  }
}

function getAllValuesInColumn() {
      var values = []
      var columnNumber = 62; // Column number for BJ
      var startRow = 2; // Starting from row 2
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Get the number of the last row with content in the sheet
      try{
        var values = sheet.getRange(startRow, columnNumber, lastRow - startRow + 1).getValues(); // Get all values from BJ2 onwards
        new_values = Object.keys(values)
        Logger.log("new_values is "+typeof(new_values))
      }
      catch(error){
        Logger.log("Error in try catch getvalueincolumn "+error)
    
      }


      finally{
        Logger.log('Get All Values In Column done')
        Logger.log("All values in column are "+values)
        Logger.log("Type of :"+typeof(values))
        checkSubstring(values,'20231024_SO412310E2005332_5.txt')
        return values
      }
    }
```

It returns the following `Execution Log`:
[image]

The string exists in `values` however javascript renders as doesn't exist.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your showing script, it seems that `values` of `checkSubstring(values,'20231024_SO412310E2005332_5.txt')` is a 2-dimensional array from `var values = sheet.getRange(startRow, columnNumber, lastRow - startRow + 1).getValues();`. But, in your function `checkSubstring(arraynya,findnya)`, `if (arraynya.includes(findnya)) {` is used. `includes` can be used to a 1-dimensional array. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In order to remove this, how about the following modification?

Please modify your function `checkSubstring(arraynya,findnya)` as follows.

#### From:

```
if (arraynya.includes(findnya)) {
```

#### To:

```
if (arraynya.flat().includes(findnya)) {
```

or

```
if (arraynya.some(([bj]) => bj == findnya)) { // or if (arraynya.find(([bj]) => bj == findnya)) {
```

#### References:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Thanks. Will do. However when i printed `print(typeOf(values))` it shows `object`. How do i distinguish between 1 or 2 dimensional array?

Comment: @Cignitor Thank you for replying. About your new question of `However when i printed print(typeOf(values)) it shows object. How do i distinguish between 1 or 2 dimensional array?`, in your situation, the official document of `getValues()` says `Object[][] — A two-dimensional array of values.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) From this, you can see the values retrieved by `sheet.getRange(startRow, columnNumber, lastRow - startRow + 1).getValues()` is a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @Cignitor Or, do you want to confirm whether the unknown object is a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Yes @Tanaike i want to confirm if the unknown object is a 2-dimensional array. Every time i print `typeOf()` apps script only returns `object`.

When I tried `Logger.log(values)` it displayed as `All values in columns are`. I expect it would be displayed as `All values in columns are [values]` with square bracket so it marked as 2 dimensional array (array inside of array)

Comment: @Cignitor Thank you for replying. Before I answer to your new question, first, I would like to confirm whether I could correctly understand your question. I understood that you wanted to search a value `'20231024_SO412310E2005332_5.txt'` from `var values = sheet.getRange(startRow, columnNumber, lastRow - startRow + 1).getValues();`. And, you want to remove your issue of `The string exists in values however javascript renders as doesn't exist.`. My answer is for this. Is my understanding correct? From your replies, I'm worried that I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Cignitor About your new question, if you want to check whether the object is a 2-dimensional array, how about `const check = Array.isArray(object) && Array.isArray(object[0]) && !Array.isArray(object[0][0]);`? If `object` is a 2-dimensional array, `true` is returned. By the way, I would like to recommend resolving your questions in order. I deeply apologize for this.